# How to create a new Database by SQLite programmatically in Cocoa for OSX?

Tags: cocoa, sqlite, nstask

In a program , I need to let user to save data to a SQLite database ( a "Save as " Option ).
I did it by using NSTask for sending a command like: "sqlite3 ./mydatbase.db" as a Terminal command  . It works fine on my own Mac, but not on others' without Xcode installed ( As SQLite installs with Xcode ).
Here is the problem: Is there any way to make a new Database ( not a new Table) programmatically for systems without SQLite ?
Any answer appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to open a database file that does not exist, SQLite creates it automatically.